# get time in past from current time

Tags: python, time

Scenario A:
Suppose the current time is 3 am on Jan 12th, 2014, I want to get two times in past for midnight just before 3 am and noon just before 3 am

So, I am looking at getting 00:00 hours of Jan 12th and noon of Jan 11th from the current time of 3 am on Jan 12th, 2014

Scenario B:

Suppose the current time is 6:37 pm on Jan 13th, 2014, I want to get two times in past for midnight just before 6:37 pm and noon just before 3 pm
So, I am looking at getting 00:00 hours of Jan 13th and noon of Jan 13th for the current time of 6:37 pm on Jan 13th, 2014

The times can be in epoch - I am just not able to figure out the math to get the two times given a current time.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine a date and time using `datetime.datetime.combine`, so you can get just the current date:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
```

Create your times, e.g.:

```
midday = datetime.time(hour=12)
```

And add them together, e.g.:

```
midday_today = datetime.datetime.combine(today, midday)
```

This is much less complicated than trying to add or subtract times from the current time. To decide whether you want today or yesterday, you can check whether we are before or after `midday`:

```
if datetime.datetime.now().time() < midday:
```

Putting this together:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

today = now.date()

midnight = datetime.time(hour=0)
midday = datetime.time(hour=12)

last_midnight = datetime.datetime.combine(today, midnight)
if now.time() < midday:
    yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    last_midday = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday, midday)
else:
    last_midday = datetime.datetime.combine(today, midday)
```

Comment: great I will try this out in sometime and let you know. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tested your answer to work for my requirements. I will accept it - it would be greatly appreciated if you could also include a way to convert the last_midnight and last_midday to epoch in the timezone of the server running this code.....

Comment: For the Unix epoch, use `(last_midnight - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()` (note the epoch started at midnight UTC).